# Detect if variable contains string, then find word after that string in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I want to make a batch file to detect if the word `I'm` exists somewhere in the variable, then to find the word after `I'm` and place it in a variable. It's like a DadBot. Here's my code:

```
if /I "%message:~0,4%"=="i'm "
```

But I want this to happen anywhere in the string. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Perhaps you could use, `@If Not "%message:I'm =%"=="%message%" Echo The string "I'm " exists within "%message%"` Obviously you could make it case insensitive, if required and remove the space too, _although I'd recommend neither_.

Comment: As this site is not here to create code you have not attempted yourself, or to answer multiple questions at a time, I am not going to answer your second question, _(you must do that yourself)_. Also please note that the method above, is not particularly robust, when there are possible poison character issues. I would often suggest enabling delayed expansion for  this type of action, but of course, I'll guarantee that you also want those variables to contain `!`'s too which would be problematic in such cases. My advice would be not to use batch for this, instead opting for a powershell solution

Comment: MegaBatchGames, please do not ignore the comments, especially when a potential solution and advice is providedd within them. Please also note that, if your end user is free to type whatever they want into the value of the `%message%` variable, then without some relatively significant validation procedures, batch files are certainly not the a recommended way of achieving your task.

Comment: Okay. I'll try not to ignore any more comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@echo off
set token=1
echo "%message%" | find "I'm" >nul 2>&1 && goto yeah
goto notmatch 

:yeah
for /f "tokens=%token% delims= " %%a in ('echo "%message%"') do if "%%~a"=="I'm" set /a myword=token+1 & goto break
set /a token += 1
goto yeah

:break
for /f "tokens=%myword% delims= " %%a in ('echo "%message%"') do set theword=%%a
echo %theword%
pause >nul 

:notmach
echo not found
pause
```

Comment: Wasif Hasan, `echo %message%` is, _as my comment was_, only robust when you can guarantee that no poison characters exist within the expanded variable content. It would certainly be safer to use `echo "%message%"`, for that reason.

Comment: Ok I am adding it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check for the search string (`I'm`). If it is found, then cut everything until the search string, then get the first word from the rest:

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :GetName "I'm Stephan"
echo %name%
call :GetName "You know, I'm Stephan!"
echo %name%
call :GetName "I'm Stephan, as you know"
echo %name%
call :GetName "There is no search string"
echo %name%
goto :eof

:GetName
set "var=%~1"
if "%var:I'm =x%" == "%var%" set "name=none" & goto :eof
set "var=%var:*I'm =%"
for /f "delims=.,;! " %%a in ("%var%") do set "name=%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already selected an answer. Here is another way using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

Using a regex is much more powerful and maintainable.

```
$strings = @(
    "I'm Stephan"
    "You know, I'm Stephan!"
    "I'm Stephan, as you know"
    "There is no search string"
)

foreach ($string in $strings) {
    if ($string -match "i'm ([a-zA-Z]*)") {
        $Matches[1]
    } else {
        "No match for === $string"
    }
}
```